# VBA: Accessing a .csv's creation date

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am using an add-in to streamline the creation of a report from raw data available in spreadsheet. The raw data usded to be available is an .xlsx file, where now it's available in .csv.

As part of tracking where the data comes from I use the following code to access the Creation Date of the spreadsheet.

```
Dim ReportBook as Workbook
Dim DataBook as Workbook

Set ReportBook = Workbooks("Report.xlsx")
Set DataBook = Workbooks("Data.csv")

With ReportBook.Worksheets("Admin")
    .Cells(1, 1) = Format(DataBook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date"), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")
End With
```

I have checked that both `ReportBook` and `DataBook` are correctly referring to their intended files.

When I tried to use .csv file as `DataBook` I got both an Automation error and Unspecified error. I can see this being related to the fact DataBook is now a .csv rather than an .xlsx. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably failing because a CSV file doesn't contain the same meta data as a proper Excel Workbook.  Try using the FileSystemObject that is part of the Scripting library instead:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/73458-read-external-file-properties-date-created-using-visual-basic-applications.html

**Edit:**

A version of the code outlined in the link:

```
Sub Test()
    MsgBox CreationDate(Workbooks("Data.csv").FullName)
End Sub

Public Function CreationDate(FullPath As String) As Date
    CreationDate = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(FullPath).DateCreated
End Function
```

Comment: Good observation about the metadata, and good suggestion for a workaround.

Comment: I always wonder whether the link is enough as it may get deleted (ok, with MrExcel it probably won't) or whether to post a sample of the code.  Hope you don't mind @Steveo40 if I just add a version of the code to your answer - no point adding a separate answer saying the same thing.